# How to add more code logic to spark/scala's getOrElse()?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

In Spark rdd's join function, we could use getOrElse() function like this:

```
rdd_a.leftOuterJoin(rdd_b) { (id, data_a, data_b) => 
    data_b.getOrElse(0)
}
```

But I want to add more complex code logic to the getOrElse function, and I do not know how to do that.

For example, if I want to generate a array of Gaussian distribution random variables

```
rdd_a.leftOuterJoin(rdd_b) { (id, data_a, data_b) => 
    arr = new Array[Double](10)
    arr.map(_=>Utils.random.nextGaussian())
    data_b.getOrElse(arr)
}
```

But you know, there are only few pair without data_b after leftOuterJoin, if I generate a array for every join-pair, it is a waste...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build the array in the `.getOrElse()` :

```
rdd_a.leftOuterJoin(rdd_b) { (id, data_a, data_b) => 
    data_b.getOrElse{
        arr = new Array[Double](10)
        arr.map(_=>Utils.random.nextGaussian())
    }
}
```

`Option`'s `.getOrElse()` is lazy (I don't have spark handy, but an example in scala) :

```
scala> List().headOption.getOrElse{ println("Building an array then."); Array(1) }
Building an array then.
res1: Array[Int] = Array(1)

scala> List(1).headOption.getOrElse{ println("Building an array then."); Array(1) }
res2: Any = 1
```

---

By the way you can create a n-element array with specific values directly using `.fill` (rather than creating it and then mapping over it) :

```
scala> Array.fill(3)(Random.nextGaussian)
res6: Array[Double] = Array(-0.2773138805049755, -1.4178827462945545, -0.8710624835785054)
```